# How to determine API version of Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am using [kafka-python](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/) for accessing Kafka. I try to create a Kafka Producer:

```
kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'])
```

but this fails with exception *kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable*.

I've found out I need to add `api_version` parameter to the KafkaProducer:

```
kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
                               api_version=(0, 10, 1))
```

This command works.

The question is: **how to determine value of `api_version`**?

`kafka-broker-api-versions.sh  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092` gives me something, but I am not sure if there's a number I can use. I tried random values like `api_version=(20, 2, 1)` and it also worked.

Comment: Ideally, it's the version of Kafka you've installed, or the lowest version you're targeting. `0.10.2` is a safe default

Comment: I am more interested in *why* is it a safe default. Source?

Comment: That's that point at which *any version* of newer clients should work - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, that's useful. I assume I can set any version to `api_version` parameter in KafkaProducer constructor, if it does not exist the class selects something on its own.

Answer (score 4):

This was solved in the discussion in the comments already:

> Ideally, it's the version of Kafka you've installed, or the lowest
> version you're targeting. 0.10.2 is a safe default
>
> That's that point at which any version of newer clients should work -
> cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Answer (score -2):

Let `kafka-python` **guess** your Kafka API version:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer  # pip3 install kafka-python

k = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="my-kafka.host.internal")
print(k.config['api_version'])
```